# Как разделить 2 вида пользователей, имея 2 разные таблицы

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, permissions

Имеется 2 вида пользователей - заказчики и типографии, с разным набором полей. У них должны быть настроены права доступа к разным страницам. Вся проблема в том, что абсолютно непонятно, как их разделять. Если бы они содержали одинаковый набор полей, то можно было бы в базе хранить роли для каждого, и с помощью AuthorizeAttributes определять в контроллерах доступ к страницам. Но так как таблицы разные, то надо лезть в эти таблицы по отдельности и искать там пользователя. К тому же, у них могут совпадать логины и id, и может возникнуть коллизия.

Как можно в этом случае организовать систему ролей?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно в User хранить оба типа пользователй.

```
class User : IdentityUser<int> {
   public Client Client { get;set;}
   public PrintHouse PrintHouse {get;set;}
}
```

При этом либо Client либо PrintHouse == null.

В имени пользователя вы можете например email записывать, но само имя хранить в `Client` и `PrintHouse`. Таблицы разные поэтому коллизии не будет. Аналогично с Id.

Роли вы сами в системе назначаете, можете просто для клиентских ролей и типографских сделать разные префиксы. Если вы в ролях храните ещё дополнительную информацию, то можно так же разделить как показал выше про пользователей.

Comment: А как разделить для них экшны? Проблема в том, что при использовании AuthorizeAttributes в метод GetRolesForUser(от интерфейса RoleProvider) приходит идентификатор пользователя. Как мне получить роль по этому идентификатору? У меня ведь 2 таблицы, и там идентификаторы могут пересекаться.

Comment: Так смотрите у вашего пользователя вне зависимости от типа будет свой уникальный Id и name. И тоже самое у роли. А вот внутри Client и PrintHouse уже будут свои Id и имя. А вы будете искать по Name внешнего User как я написал в примере.

Comment: А, то есть вы имеете в виду то, что и на уровне базы данных сделать абстрактную таблицу User, и от нее уже наследовать PrintHouse и Client?

Comment: Я предложил не наследовать, а просто в неё вложить, подключить.

Comment: Ну да, я неправильно выразился. Абстрактную таблицу User связать с двумя другими, так?

Comment: Но с наследованием тоже вариант можно попробовать, тут зависит от того какую версию EF вы используете, я сейчас пишу на EF Core 2.0 там с наследование для данного примера будет некрасиво, так как реализован только подход TPH - https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/4.1.php.

Comment: Да, вы правильно поняли.

Comment: Я не использую EF, исключительно ADO.NET. Спасибо за помощь)

Comment: Так вы работаете без ASP.NET Identity? Тогда просто делаете отдельные таблички и не надо париться. Это с ASP.NET Identity проблема возникает, так как в ней не предполагается два вида пользователей и два вида ролей. И вам просто не надо использовать системные атрибуты для этого. Просто делайте проверку в коде, или напишите свою версию аттрибутов.

Comment: А проверки в коде не приведут к излишним запросам к БД? Производительность приложения не сядет?

Comment: Смотря какой код вы напишите. Если вы будете из кэша роли например брать или из claims, то тогда будет без запросов к БД. Ведь проверка через атрибут тоже каким-то кодом написана )) И ваш код может быть ничуть не хуже того который проверяет через аттрибуты.

Comment: Я вас понял, огромное спасибо за уделенное время)

Comment: Я у себя в проекте, так как ролей у меня не много, их храню всё время в приложении в оперативной памяти.

Comment: Пожалуйста, рад был помочь.